# how to get yesterday starttime in UTC using momentjs

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to get the epoch seconds using momentjs.

For example, time right now is `2019-04-20T15:07:04.388Z` EST, I want to get yesterday start time epoch `2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z` in UTC.

I have tried the below code -

```
    const now = new Date();
    const start = moment(now) // get current datetime
        .utcOffset(0) // convert to UTC
        .subtract(24, "hours") // go 24 hours into the past
        .startOf("day") // get the start of the date we landed on
        .unix(); // get unix timestamp
    console.log(now);
    console.log(start);
```

The output of the above program is  -

```
    Sat Apr 20 2019 15:11:23 GMT-0400 (EDT) {}
    1555650000
```

According to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php the  1555650000 translates to `Fri, 19 Apr 2019 05:00:00 +0000`. But I want it to be `Fri, 19 Apr 2019 00:00:00 +0000` in UTC.

The momentjs version used in our code -

```
"moment": "2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.23"
```

Any idea how can I get this?

Comment: Is it you should provide a different offset based on your timezone? Can you try utcOffset(moment.parseZone(now).utcOffset()) instead of utcOffset(0) ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, I get the correct result using your code in my env with lastest version of moment, maybe you can share a snippet. As a general rule, you can use [`moment()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) instead of `moment(new Date())` and [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) instead of `moment(now).utcOffset(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one line statement

```
console.log( moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day').toString());
```

Output : Sun Apr 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000